# Why does application insight log 400 bad request as successful request and not log exception

Tags: azure, logging, exception, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

i am encountering a problem i'm not familiar with.

So i'm trying to log exceptions from a test Azure Function but when i throw an exception and return a 400 bad request, application insight registers the log as a successful request.

As i understand it it is probably register the function's successful run but what i don't understand is how i then should log the exception.

So what i have done so far is this.

(I Will be referring to Application Insights as AI from here on out)

I started by created an AI-Resource.

Then i took the instrument key and applied it to the app settings of my function.

After that i installed the AI NUGET to my function bu creating a Projet.json file and then pasting something like this which installed the necessary assemblies and such.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
  "net46":{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.4.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

after this i initialize the TelemetryClient in the function and try to log and exception in a catch:

Initiation:

```
    string key = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient() { 
    InstrumentationKey = key 
    };
```

Catch:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> properties = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    properties.Add("Function Payload", data.ToString());
    properties.Add("Function Exception", e.ToString());

    telemetry.TrackException(e, properties);

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
}
```

Test running the function i get:

```
2018-03-07T14:24:36.171 [Info] Function started (Id=0292b455-314d-4c4c-872a-2b8137a72305)
2018-03-07T14:24:37.092 [Info] Function completed (Success, Id=0292b455-314d-4c4c-872a-2b8137a72305, Duration=931ms)
```

[image: Test function result window]

In Application insights i can can only see bad requests for StatusCode: 500
but 400 Bad requests gets logged as Successful requests.

And also the TrackException functionality doesn't log any of the custom properties...

[image]

So what am i missing?

MORE DETAILS ABOUT EXCEPTION LOGGING:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mikhail is right that we treat this as a success because the function is a success. We didn't want to use status codes to guess whether there was a successful operation or not, so we look for whether the function threw an exception.

Your exception isn't appearing in that screen because it hasn't been property correlated with this function execution. If you go to App Insights Analytics and query for that `ExceptionTelemetry`, you should see it.

In order to correlate it with a specific function, you'd need to set the `OperationId`, which is the same as the function's `InvocationId`. There is a sample that shows how to do this with Events, Metrics, and Dependencies, but doing it for Exceptions is the same (you can ignore the `User.Id` assignment): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions

---

Update: From what you've shown of your function above, you may be able to get away with doing something like:

```
catch (Exception e)
{    
    log.Error("Function Payload " + data.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

That would return a 500 (rather than a 400), and Functions would log the trace to Application Insights, and then log the exception as well as the Request failure. If you're not using your `TelemetryClient` anywhere else, you could remove that from your code.

Comment: Ok, I'll definitely check that out. Thank you! :)

Comment: Just another question @brettsam, should i still catch the exception?

Comment: My response was getting complicated, so look at the update to my answer and see if that helps.

Comment: That helped Thank you, it feels like some kind of workaround though :P But if thats how i gain control over what i want to do then so be it :P
Thanks for the answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

The server (Azure Function) processed the request without errors, you returned a result from it, so from the point of view of Function App runtime the request was processed successfully. You can see that from the log too:

> ... Function completed (Success, ...

So, it makes sense that the Function App registers the call as success in Application Insights too. At least, that's how they chose to implement it.

Comment: Hmm, So is that the reason my TrackException attempt isnt working, as in registering properties too?

Comment: `TrackException` should work regardless. But you only have screenshot of Request event summary, not Exception details, so hard to say

Comment: Hmm, well i didn't get any exception details in Application insights because it does't log anything at all. But i'll update the question with more screenshots of what i have. Thanks Mikhail.

Comment: i have put up some more information, just tell me if there is anything else you need to see to get a better understanding. I'm pretty new to this hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

the "for this operation" not showing exceptions implies that the exception that you sent does not have the same operationId as the azure function.  operation 
id is how application insights "links" related telemetry together.

your "exeption logging" screenshot is not an `exception`, but a `request`, so the custom properties logged on your exception won't be there.

if you want your azure function to fail, and show as a failed request, and log an exception, why are you catching the exception and logging it yourself?   doesn't catching the exception then cause the azure function to succeed?  why not just let the exception trickle out and let the function runtime do that part for you? (doesn't it?)

Comment: You make a valid point, me being new to this feels like i gain more control of how i can form my exception when trying to do it manually rather than letting the function runtime throw the exception. but i understand what you are saying. Still what if i want to log custom data into the exception. would you be able to do that letting the runtime take care of the exception throwing so to speak or am i out wondering in the forest right now? :P